# ACL not blocking IP or ICMP packets out of an interface

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer, acl

I created this network to do some general practice. Every host on the network can ping every other host. The routers are just using a basic RIPv2 configuration. All of the interfaces can ping all the other interfaces.

I created a basic ACL on Router 3 on the right. As you can see by my picture, the ACL is configured for blocking both IP and ICMP packets destined for 10.10.2.2. I place this ACL on FA1/0 out of Router 3 and it is still not filtering out the packets when I ping.

Any thoughts as to why packets destined for this host are still getting through when the ACL is clearly configured to filter these packets?

Config:

```
Router(config)#ip access-list extended Divide

Router(config-ext-nacl)#deny ip any host 10.10.2.2

Router(config-ext-nacl)#deny icmp an host 10.10.2.2 

Router(config-ext-nacl)#permit ip any any

Router(config-ext-nacl)#exit

Router(config)#interface fastEthernet 1/0

Router(config-if)#ip access-group Divide out

Router(config-if)#exit
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your configurations to question

Comment: @infra for every router and host ?

Comment: I can't see, your configurations on interface.

Comment: No R3 is enough

Comment: @infra Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in your situation, because You are going to block IP address which is not connected in interface. If you apply this configuration on Router which is having 10.10.2.1 (`Router which next to 10.10.2.2`) will be worked.

> ACL needs to implement in most closet interface.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that but let me ask you this: Why can't I used an extended ACL on R3 if I am specifying the destination address of Server 2?

Comment: It is a prerequisite to implement acl

Comment: I just did what you said and Im still able to ping.

deny ip 172.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host 10.10.2.2

Comment: I did this on the router next to server 2 to and implemented in on Fa0/0

Comment: change to your ACL `deny icmp x.x.x.  host y.y.y.y echo` And make sure that direction is **out**

Comment: Got it to work. What is the echo for?

Comment: Echo is like the call, and echo reply is the answer to that call.